# Filter in data according to their value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database and in their all users their friends are stored (value is true if they are friends). But if the other person hasn't accepted the friend request yet, the value is false.

[image]

I can put all those users in a list. But what I want to achieve is that only the users with value 'true' are showed and those with value 'false' not.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("friends").child(userUID);
ref.on('value', gotFriends);

function gotFriends(data) {
    var usernames = data.val();
    var names = Object.keys(usernames);

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var uname = names[i];
        var ul = document.getElementById("friendsList");
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uname));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can just add `names.filter(name => usernames[name])` which will only keep the items in the `names` array for which the corresponding key in `usernames` is `true`.

Comment: @Ohad Thank you for the answer. Where exactly should I add this?

Comment: Just below `var names = Object.keys(...` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function gotFriends(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(friend) {
      var uname = friend.key;
      if (friend.val() === true) {
        var ul = document.getElementById("friendsList");
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uname));
        ul.appendChild(li);
      }
    }
}
```

In addition to the `if`, this code uses `Snapshot.forEach()` to loop over the results. It doesn't change the behavior, but is slightly faster and more idiomatic.